Brother iprint&scan issues
I have a Brother MFC-L2750DW connected via WiFi to a Windows 10 computer.
The iPrint&Scan utility always showed my printer as offline, even though I could print and scan most of the times.
(I say "most", because sometimes it would lose connection and I would need to remove and re-add the printer, which is a bother).
Today it popped up a message that an update is available, and after installing the update, it shows the following:

The message is unhelpful, but I assume it wants me to update tithe firmware, which I don't want to do since people claim that Brother's new firmware prevents the use of 3rd-party toner.
Is there a way around it?

Never update printer f/w unless the documentation clearly states that it will fix your problem.
